# C check what service is running on an open port

Tags: c, port-scanning

I'm writing a port scanner in C and i want to detect what service is running on an open port and its version.
I've already wrote the scanner code but now i have no idea about how to detect running service.
What can i do?

Comment: You can check it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Consider the [IANA well-known-ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml).

Comment: I know what service is *teorically* running on a port (22->ssh) but what i would like to know is: how can i check *for sure* what service is running and the version of it.

Comment: You may not be able to achieve this with complete accuracy. You can make an educated guess based on what port the service is running on, and if you're so inclined you can code up minimal "clients" for each service and test - if they respond as expected, you can tag it as that service. But it should be obvious that this isn't a task that can *ever* be accomplished with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

If you are determined to do it in your own code, you can connect to the port, see if you get any data on it, if nothing then send a few bytes, and check again.

Then match that against expected response.

to get an idea what you are looking for, you can connect manually to the port with telnet and poke at it. In many cases (a web server is an easy example) you must send some correctly formatted data in order to get a usable response.

nmap has done all this and much more (e.g. extensive checks such as looking for byte order and timing of arp traffic)

UPDATE: several people have mentioned well known ports, but that won't help you discover standard services running on nonstandard ports, such as ssh or http servers running on custom ports.

Comment: I agree with everything here, but will repeat what I said in my comment above: you will not be able to achieve this with 100% accuracy, even if you code up "minimal clients" for every protocol known to man.

Comment: @NikBougalis Absolutely true. The ways to detect and the data you need to send across to get a response is almost endless. I wouldn't undertake a project like this except a) for fun, or b) for in-house custom services that nmap wouldn't know

Answer (score 1):

If server sends something first, use that to identify protocol.

If not, send something according to some protocol, such as http, and see what server sends back (valid response or error). You may need to make several attempts with different protocols, and a good order is important to minimize connection count.

Some protocols may be very hard to identify, and it is easy to make custom server with unique protocol you don't know about, or even hide real server under simple fake server of other proto such as http.

If you just want to know what the port usually is, check ["well known ports"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) and official [reserved ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers).

Also check [nmap](http://nmap.org/) source code.